# Fetching in nuxt(3)

Tags: frontend, nuxt.js

I have a async fetch function that doesn't seem to be called in nuxt. Here's what I have.

```
async fetch(){
console.log("TEST")
this.stay = await this.$axios.$get('myURL')
}
```

TEST doesn't show up anywhere in the logs and my backend is unresponsive so I don't think this function is even being called. I've tried a couple of different ways to fetch this data including http and axios. Following the example from https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/data-fetching/#usefetch

```
const {data: stay} = await useFetch('myURL')
```

Hasn't helped either. I know my backend is working alright because I can curl it.
I'm pretty lost, does anyone know what's going on or give me ideas?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What do you see in your network tab (browser devtools)?

Comment: @kissu I see a lot of 200 ok codes relating to node modules, with the last ones involving the related vue file and a 101 code. Nothing indicating that something is going to the backend.

Comment: Mind sharing your `nuxt.config.js`, `package.json` and trying a simple fetch on a brand new page?